# setOnItemClickListener() not working on gridView

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-gridview

I know this is already been asked, but somehow the solutions do not work for me.

I have a `gridView` which is inflated by a `relativeLayout`. The adapter sets perfectly, When I add a `clickListener` to one of the childs of `relativeLayout` they also work fine. But not the `itemClickListener` on the `gridview`.

Here is what I have tried:

Gridview:

```
<GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:clipToPadding="true"
            android:columnWidth="170dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
</GridView>
```

Relativelayout added in gridview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rlImage"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:paddingBottom="7dp"
    android:paddingRight="7dp" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/noimage" />

    <!-- <ImageButton -->
    <!-- android:id="@+id/imageHover" -->
    <!-- android:layout_width="220dp" -->
    <!-- android:layout_height="220dp" -->
    <!-- android:adjustViewBounds="true" -->
    <!-- android:background="@null" -->
    <!-- android:scaleType="fitXY" -->
    <!-- android:src="@drawable/tile_selector_style" /> -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ShowTitle"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:hint="Show Title"
        android:paddingBottom="40dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ShowTime"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:hint="Show Time"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The setting of gridview listener:

```
gv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.v("griditem", "clicked");
                Toast.makeText(context, "Here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
```

No idea whats going wrong here..

Comment: I think you should use `linearLayout.gv.setOnItemClickListener`

Comment: try to remove this properties from your grid item  android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

Comment: @Kedarnath my gv is: `public static GridView gv;` `gv = (GridView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.gridView);`

Comment: ok try to set this  `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to your `RelativeLayout` and remove `android:focusable="false"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` from every child

Comment: @Haresh from all the items inside the `relativelayout`?

Comment: yes and also from relative layout too.

Comment: @SimplePlan it is working now. Thanks. Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

try to set  `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to your `RelativeLayout`

and remove `android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` from every child

Answer (score 15):

Hey folks this is how i solved the problem;

While using clickable objects in the grid then unfortunately android can not handle the click event of grid.

SO USE use interface view.

Example: USE IMAGEVIEW INSTEAD OF IMAGEBUTTON AND BUTTON

if you need to show some text in that image use textview and align that on top of imageview.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding onitemclicklistener in my gridviewadapter itself(inside getview method).

I don't know whether this practice is right or wrong but it worked for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30715769)